# How to properly configure and use LXC through lxc-tools (NOT libvirt) on Red Hat based distros?

Tags: centos, virtualization, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am currently learning all about LXC. No doubt there are excellent tutorials about it. The
tutorials/guides take one of the following approach:

1. LXC on Ubuntu/Debian etc. using lxc-tools
   OR
2. LXC on RHEL/CentOS using libvirt

However the requirement is for lxc-tools on RHEL/CentOS and I can't find much about it.
If I try to use Ubuntu tutorial they talk about apparmor,upstart which are not available
and installing will have unexpected results.

Help.
Thanks.